# If else statement is not working after clicking button in the browser

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom

I want to build a game using Javascript, DOM, HTML, and CSS. My logic is as follows:

Step 1: Clicking three buttons execute three different functions, named random1, random2, and random3. Each function will generate two random numbers. (Suppose 1 and 2).

Step2: Checking the result of these functions by using `if`/`else-if` conditions.

Step3: If the return value of all the buttons equals 1, it will alert ("player 1 wins").
Similarly, if value is 2, "player 2 wins" will be alerted.

Step4: If values do not equal to each other, the program will ask to refresh the browser.

But the problem is, when I run this code in the browser only the else statement is working and if/else-if is not working. Another problem: else statements work before displaying the random number in the <`p/>` tag when clicking 'button number three'.

```
//My Code//

var a;
function random1(){
    a = Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1);
    document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = a;
    return a;       
}
let p1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
p1.addEventListener("click", random1);

var b
function random2(){
    b = Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1);
    document.getElementById("para2").innerHTML = b;
    return b;       
}

let t2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2")
t2.addEventListener("click",random2);

var c
function random3(){
    c=Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1);
    document.getElementById("para3").innerHTML = c; 
    return c;    
}

let r3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
r3.addEventListener("click",check(a,b,c));
r3.addEventListener("click",random3);


function check(s,t,u){
    if(s===1 && t===1 && u===1){
        alert("Players 1 Wins");
    }
    else if(s===2 && t===2 && u===2){
        alert("Player 2 Wins");
    }
    else{
        alert("Refresh the Browser");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should consider using `if (s==='1'...)` instead of `if (s===1...)`. try that and let us know

Comment: @assembler I doubt that is the issue, as those variables are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
r3.addEventListener("click",check(a,b,c))
```

The function must be a listener, which will be called by the browser when the event occurs.
To solve it you can do something like that.

```
r3.addEventListener("click",() => {
   check(a,b,c)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have a typo in `alert"Refresh the Browser");`

Missing a `(` bracket.

Next, when you have to pass parameters to listeners, use anonymous functions that calls specified function with the parameters so that it gets executed when the event occurs.

You can do this.

```
r3.addEventListener("click",function(){
    check(a,b,c));
}
```

Or you can use arrow functions if you prefer.

```
r3.addEventListener("click",() => {
    check(a,b,c));
}
```

Lastly and most importantly the main problem with your code is ordering of eventListener.

```
r3.addEventListener("click",random3);
r3.addEventListener("click",check(a,b,c));
```

You might want to call `random3` first to set the value of `c` and then check, so keep that above.

Comment: I have done accordingly. Unfortunately, it cannot fix the problem. :(

Comment: Inside `check` function, print the values of all the parameters and find out which value is different. Plus you've 3 random variables. It has highly less chances of all being equal anyway. Check for yourself with `console.log(s,t,u)` in first line inside `check` function. I think the code is fine if you have followed steps above. It is going to else because s, t and u are not equal to 1 or 2 most of the time. Assign them to 1 or 2 instead of using random and then see if your code is working or not.

Comment: Please check this link and you will find a matching game. I am trying to build such a game. https://sazzadador.000webhostapp.com/tictac/index.htm

Comment: Actually, I am unable to continue because of this else problem. I am not asking for the total help. I have shared it so that it can help you to understand my thinking. Thanks for your suggestion.